# cURL not properly downloading images

Tags: php, drupal, curl

I'm having a problem with cURL.  I am downloading images and saving them to a folder.  The file that cURL creates has the right filesize, which makes me think that the headers are being read properly.  But, when I open the file up in my browser or in any picture-viewing application, only a tiny bit at the top appears to actually have been written.  My code:

```
function _vancore_curl_savefile($url) {
  $url = str_replace("\"", "", $url);
  $basename = basename($url);
  $basename = str_replace("%20", "_", $basename);
  $var = file_directory_path() . "/van/" . $basename;
  $uvar = "files/van/" . $basename;
  $handle = fopen($var, "w");
  $curl = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $handle);
  $result = curl_exec($curl);
  $result2 = $result;
  curl_close($curl);
  fclose($handle);
  return $uvar;
}
```

`file_directory_path()` is a Drupal function (this function is part of a Drupal module and called for each file that needs to be downloaded) that returns the path to the Drupal file download directory.  I have confirmed through various tests that:

a) `$url` is what it should be
b) `fopen()` is opening the right file
c) `curl_exec()` is returning `true` after it is executed

I am very confused about what is going wrong here.  Anyone have any thoughts?

TIA,
Benjy

Comment: What dou you mean with "a tiny bit at the top"? Is the file as such viewable? If you download JPEGs I doubt, that it could even be viewed, if the download would be only partial.

Comment: I think you need to do something with GD or ImageMagic
http://www.bitrepository.com/download-image.html

Comment: Your code works fine for me as it is. The pictures display properly in both browsers and image apps.

Comment: @Boldewyn - when downloading a GIF, a tiny bit at the top is visible, but the bulk of the file is not there.  When downloading a PNG, I get a message in Firefox that "the file cannot be displayed, because it contains errors."

@GZipp - so where would the error be coming from then?  Something prematurely ending the transmission, perhaps?  A php.ini setting I missed?

Thanks.

Comment: Since you said that "the file that cURL creates has the right filesize", I assumed that the download was complete, and that by "the right filesize" you meant that it matched the size of the file you want to download. You could try using Wireshark to see what is happening with the transmission from and to the remote server, for instance if your machine is terminating the connection early. Have you tried it with more than one image, and from more than one server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't happen to be using the curl library "emulation" in the Drupal curl module. Are you? That doesn't always work. Make sure you have the real PHP curl library installed.

Comment: Wow, that was it!  Can't believe it was something so simple.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Set:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
```

Comment: Still the same problem.  I also tried just setting that flag (and not CURLOPT_FILE) and then writing the results of the operation to the file, but the same problem persisted.

Answer (score 1):

Try if this helps:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you're missing `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);` (along with `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`, as said above)

[Here](http://www.edmondscommerce.co.uk/blog/php/php-save-images-using-curl/) is an example.